# SVG : viewbox property strech text inside

Tags: css, svg, text, viewbox

I have a histo bar chart with viewbox property on svg element.

I can not find a solution with the text inside which is stretched as you can see below.

Obviously, I don't want to externalize text elements from `g` elements.

```css
svg path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #003B56;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <g>
        <g transform="translate(0, 0)" class="2013">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="0" y="95" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <text shape-rendering="crispEdges" dy="10" dx="16.666666666666668" style="text-anchor: middle; font-size: 8px; fill: rgb(140, 140, 140); width: 33.3333%; height: 66.6667%;">2013</text>
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="85" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="hidden" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(33.333333333333336, 0)" class="2014">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="0" y="95" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <text shape-rendering="crispEdges" dy="10" dx="16.666666666666668" style="text-anchor: middle; font-size: 8px; fill: rgb(140, 140, 140); width: 33.3333%; height: 66.6667%;">2014</text>
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="85" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="hidden" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(66.66666666666667, 0)" class="2015">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="0" y="95" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <text shape-rendering="crispEdges" dy="10" dx="16.666666666666668" style="text-anchor: middle; font-size: 8px; fill: rgb(140, 140, 140); width: 33.3333%; height: 66.6667%;">2015</text>
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="85" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="hidden" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(100, 0)" class="2015">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="65.32792098352175" y="29.67207901647825" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <text shape-rendering="crispEdges" dy="10" dx="16.666666666666668" style="text-anchor: middle; font-size: 8px; fill: rgb(140, 140, 140); width: 33.3333%; height: 66.6667%;">2015</text>
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="75.76149333828752" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="visible" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(133.33333333333334, 0)" class="2016">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="70" y="25" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <text shape-rendering="crispEdges" dy="10" dx="16.666666666666668" style="text-anchor: middle; font-size: 8px; fill: rgb(140, 140, 140); width: 33.3333%; height: 66.6667%;">2016</text>
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="73.65632455308725" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="visible" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(166.66666666666669, 0)" class="2017">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="27.544350652682226" y="67.45564934731777" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <text shape-rendering="crispEdges" dy="10" dx="16.666666666666668" style="text-anchor: middle; font-size: 8px; fill: rgb(140, 140, 140); width: 33.3333%; height: 66.6667%;">2017</text>
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="81.50817238857238" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="visible" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <path transform="translate(114.58333333333333, 20)" class="data" d="M0,60.761493338287515L33.333333333333336,58.656324553087245L66.66666666666667,66.50817238857238" style="stroke: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: **What is the question?**

Comment: If you don't want things to stretch anisotropically, don't set preserveAspectRatio="none"

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is divide your SVG into two parts: the stretched bars, and the unstretched caption. Use an inner svg with `preserveAspectRatio="none"` for the bars, and position the captions with percentages. You cannot use `transform` attributes for that.

```css
svg path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #003B56;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100">
    <svg width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <g transform="translate(0, 0)" class="2013">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="0" y="95" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="85" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="hidden" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(33.333333333333336, 0)" class="2014">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="0" y="95" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="85" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="hidden" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(66.66666666666667, 0)" class="2015">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="0" y="95" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="85" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="hidden" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(100, 0)" class="2015">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="65.32792098352175" y="29.67207901647825" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="75.76149333828752" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="visible" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(133.33333333333334, 0)" class="2016">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="70" y="25" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="73.65632455308725" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="visible" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(166.66666666666669, 0)" class="2017">
            <rect class="ca" width="33.333333333333336" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" style="fill: rgb(239, 239, 239);" />
            <rect class="ca" width="16.666666666666668" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="8.333333333333334" height="27.544350652682226" y="67.45564934731777" style="fill: rgb(58, 58, 58);" />
            <rect class="marge" x="14.583333333333334" width="4.166666666666667" height="8.333333333333334" y="81.50817238857238" shape-rendering="crispEdges" visibility="visible" style="fill: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
        </g>
        <path transform="translate(114.58333333333333, 20)" class="data" d="M0,60.761493338287515L33.333333333333336,58.656324553087245L66.66666666666667,66.50817238857238" style="stroke: rgb(210, 210, 210);" />
    </svg>
    <g shape-rendering="crispEdges" style="text-anchor: middle; font-size: 8px; fill: rgb(140, 140, 140);">
        <text dy="10" dx="8.3333333333333333%">2013</text>
        <text dy="10" dx="25%">2014</text>
        <text dy="10" dx="41.666666666666667%">2015</text>
        <text dy="10" dx="58.333333333333333%">2015</text>
        <text dy="10" dx="75%">2016</text>
        <text dy="10" dx="91.666666666666667%">2017</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

You could equally position the rectangles using percentages for the horizontal values (`x` and `width`, again no `transform` attribute anywhere), and avoid placing them inside the inner svg. Albeit, for the path this is impossible.